# Edit a file inside database in php

Tags: php

When the submit button is pressed,the `isset($_POST['ta']` works,but the file is not updated inside database with '---------'. any suggestion where I am going wrong?

```
if ( isset( $_POST['ta'] ) ) {
    $handle = fopen('saw42.TextGrid', "a");
    require('db_connection.php');
    fwrite( $handle, "-----------");
    fclose( $handle );
}
```

Comment: is there any error you are getting from php??

Comment: are you getting any error messages?

Comment: What does `fwrite` have to do with a database update? Unless maybe its a plain text self formatted database?

Comment: [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) opens a *file*. I am not aware of any database working that way.

Comment: i am not getting any error messages but it is also not able to write ------ in my file...

Comment: you should check if the file is really opened `$handle!==false`

Comment: is it working without if(isset($_POST['ta']))?

Comment: @Sumurai8:actually the file is in database which i am trying to edit

Comment: @user225033 File in a database? What do you have for a database? Mysql? Mssql?

Comment: I am totally confused. how are you storing file in the database?  you do you use `fopen` for file stored in database. `fopen` is for opening `filesystem` files or `URLs`

Comment: let me put it in this way....i have a text file in database and i want to edit it....

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(isset($_POST['ta'])){


    $handle=fopen('saw42.TextGrid',"a");
    require('db_connection.php'); // don't know why this line is here
    if ($handle===false){
        echo 'Unable to open file';
    }else{
        fwrite($handle,"-----------");
        fclose($handle);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your permissions on Unix OS , Is your file is 0644 or 0444

Answer (score 0):

I pressume, the `require`-line fails and so the file is opened, but the script is aborted before something gets written inside. If errors are turned of (as is on some preconfigured systems), no error message will be shown.

Nevertheless the question is a bit confusing, since if a database (in the sense of a relational database system accessable through a database server) is meant, the code should not use any `fopen`-calls. If the 'database' is a simple file, the requirement of the `db_connection.php` seems to be unclear.

To clarify things a bit:

1. A (relational) database is a collection of tables (relations) that perhaps refer to each other. Such databases are typically filled and asked via SQL-language or some object-oriented interface (MySQL, MS-SQL, SQLITE, ...)
2. A database in the sense of 'some data' can also reference a simple file. In this case, you have to organize data by yourselves and use file access methods to access it.